# Flutter & Dart : What is an isolate in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-isolates, isolate-scope

As I study about flutter, I notices that there is a thing called `isolate`.

What is it for? And how do we implement that? Can you give me a simple example?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: https://medium.com/dartlang/dart-asynchronous-programming-isolates-and-event-loops-bffc3e296a6a

Answer (score 1):

Isolate in flutter, similar with threading.

> "Flutter is single-threaded but it is capable of doing multi-threading
> stuff using Isolates (many processes). When Dart starts, there will be
> one main Isolate(Thread). This is the main executing thread of the
> application, also referred to as the UI Thread. In simple Flutter apps
> you will only ever use one Isolate, and your app will run smoothly.
> Isolates are:
>
> Dart’s version of Threads. Do not share memory between each other.
> Uses Ports and Messages to communicate between them. May use another
> processor core if available. Runs code in parallel."

[Docs & Simple Example](http://a5.ua/blog/how-use-isolates-flutter)

> "Concurrent programming using isolates: independent workers that are
> similar to threads but don't share memory, communicating only via
> messages."

[Official Docs](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-isolate/dart-isolate-library.html)